# Nuget pack Error NU5050 when building Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I am attempting to build Xamarin.Forms from source to debug another issue.
The XF repository provides a build script which works up until packing the builds into a Nuget package. The final stage called _NugetPack fails with this error:

> Attempting to build package from 'Xamarin.Forms.temp.nuspec'.
> Error NU5050: Attempted to pack multiple files into the same location(s). The following destinations were used multiple times: lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Core.xml, lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.xml, lib\MonoAndroid10.0\Xamarin.Forms.Core.xml, lib\MonoAndroid10.0\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.xml, lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Core.xml, lib\Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.xml, lib\tizen40\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Tizen.dll

When calling Nuget directly (without using the build script):

> nuget pack ..nuspec\Xamarin.Forms.nuspec -Version 9.9.9 -Properties Configuration=Debug

The same error is thrown. I therefore suspect this not being an issue with the Xamarin.Froms build script, but with my nuget.

Nuget Version: 5.0.0+0-sha.809e75547

**Edit**
I think I figured out the problem. In case of the Tizen one, there are simply 2 of the same lines, thus having duplicate outputs. The others are using ** for globbing. While there is simply 1 directory, thus getting duplicate outputs again. Commenting these out works now.

Comment: What is the content of your nuspec file please ?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/tree/5.0.0/.nuspec all files work, except Xamarin.Forms.nuspec. @MaximeEsprit

Comment: Any luck in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be related to an open issue, documented under [Nuget pack allows multiple files with the same path to be added to a package #4388](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4388).

There are two ways to solve this issue:

#### Remove the duplicate source file entries

The `Xamarin.Forms.nuspec` file contains duplicate source file entries, for example:

```
<file src="..\build\docs\Xamarin.Forms.Core.xml" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
<file src="..\build\docs\**\Xamarin.Forms.Core.xml" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />

<file src="..\build\docs\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.xml" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
<file src="..\build\docs\**\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.xml" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
```

The `src` attributes with the `**` wildcards references the same file as the explicit `..\build\docs\Xamarin.Forms.Core.xml` value.

So to solve the issue, either remove the wildcard entries or the explicit ones, and `nuget pack` will run fine.

#### Downgrade Nuget.exe

You can also work around the issue by [downloading](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) and using a slightly older version of `Nuget.exe` like [v5.8.1](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v5.8.1/nuget.exe), e.g. by adding its directory to your `PATH` environment variable, that does not check for duplicate source files yet.